# Differential of two geometric brownian motions

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, finance

I am currently taking a finance course which includes some math that is currently above my level, it is however not a pure math class and we are just supposed to be able to apply the math to the given problems without much understanding.

The problem is the following:

We have two stochastic variables $X$ and $Y$, with $Z$ = $X$ $*$ $Y$.

We have the following equations $dX = \mu_{1} X dt + \sigma_{1} X dB_{1}(t)$ and $dY = \mu_{2} Y dt + \sigma_{2} Y dB_{2}(t)$ where $dB_(t)$ is a Wiener process.

The exercise is to calculate $dZ$.

I suppose I should apply Ito's lemma in some way but I am not sure how to approach this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add Itô's lemma (... the way you learnt in your course) to your question?

Comment: http://snag.gy/3lOHJ.jpg

Comment: So what do you obtain when you apply Itô's formula to $f(x,y) := x \cdot y$ (i.e. $n=2$, no $t$-dependence)?

Comment: "we are just supposed to be able to apply the math to the given problems without much understanding" Nice, everything is in place for [the next one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_crisis_of_2007%E2%80%9308).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that $d\langle X,Y\rangle (t) = 
\sigma_1 X(t) \times \sigma_2 Y(t) \times d\langle B_1, B_2\rangle (t) $.

According to your question, I don't know what is the link between $B_1$ and $B_2$. Then I will assume that $(B_1, B_2)$ is a vectorial gaussian process and that the correlation $\rho(B_1(t), B_2(t)) = \rho$ does not depend on $t$ (for instance, if $(B_1, B_2)$ is a Brownian motion then $\rho = 0$; if $B_1 = B_2$ then $\rho = 1$).

In that case, $d\langle B_1, B_2\rangle (t) \rho dt$. Now you are ready for the Ito formula: let $F(x,y) = xy$. Then,

\begin{align}
dZ(t) 
&= dF(X(t),Y(t)) 
= \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(X(t), Y(t)) dX(t) 
+  \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(X(t), Y(t)) dY(t) 
\\&+ \frac 12\left (
\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}(X(t), Y(t)) d\langle X,X\rangle (t)
+ 2 \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x \partial y}(X(t), Y(t)) d\langle X,Y\rangle (t)
+ \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2}(X(t), Y(t)) d\langle Y,Y\rangle (t)
\right)
\\&=Y(t) dX(t) + X(t) dY(t) 
+ \sigma_1 \sigma_2 X(t) Y(t) d\langle B_1, B_2\rangle (t)
\end{align}

This is the general product formula. Here it simplifies more:
$$
= X(t)Y(t)\left[(\mu_1 + \mu_2 + \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2)) dt + 
\sigma_1 dB_1(t) + \sigma_2 dB_2(t)
\right]
$$

---

If you just want to remember something useful, just remember the formula
$$
dX(t) = b_1(t) dt + c_1(t) dB_1(t), dY(t) = b_2(t) dt + c_2(t) dB_2(t)\\
\implies d(XY)(t) = X(t)dY(t) + Y(t) dX(t) + \rho c_1(t) c_2(t) dt
$$
with the hypothesis given earlier about $B_{1,2}$.

Comment: I guess the OP does *not* know what $\langle X,Y \rangle$ means for two stochastic processes $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$, $(Y_t)_{t \geq 0}$.

Comment: @saz in that case, applying the Ito formula seems to be a little ambitious.

Comment: Sure, I agree with you. But the OP is supposed to do this "without much understanding".

Comment: @saz I added a little somthing at the end.